# Can insert data to django test database before run test envirunment? Override Setup() didn't solve

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-testing

### problem description

I'm looking for a way to insert data to django test database before run django test. This requirement happends because urls setting is written as below.

urls.py

```
group_names = Group.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
for group in group_names :
    url(r'^{}/{}'.format(group,'webindex'), web_index)
```

for example, if there is group1 and group2 in database Group table, the url will be '/group1/webindex/' and '/group2/webindex/'. This works find when in production environment. The page show successfully. because the production database already exit group data.
However when i want to write the testcase for web_index, problem happened. Here is my code.

tests.py

```
class webindexTestCase(TransactionTestCase):
    fixtures = ['./auth_group.json']
    def test_webindex(self):
        c = Client()
        r = c.get('/group1/webindex/')
        print(r.status_code)
```

when run the test, the http response code always get 404. As far as i know, it happended because when run django test the urls were set before insert the group data to test database.
  Therefore, i'm wondering is there a way to insert data to django test database before setting urls pattern, or reset the urls pattern when run this test?

## What I have tried

1. Manually insert group data to test database then run test:
   Before run python manage.py test, insert group data to test database. Although this way work, the response code is 200. However, I'm looking for a way to automatically do this.
2. Using `setUp()`:
   I have try override Setup() in my testcase as below. This still get the 404 https respone. In my opinion, the django urls setting are run before `setUp()`.

```
class webindexTestCase(TransactionTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Group.objects.create(name='group1')

    def test_webindex(self):
        c = Client()
        r = c.get('/group1/webindex/')
        print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: Override the `setUp` method. see the docs here: https://django-testing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_unittests.html#a-couple-neat-features

Comment: Still get 404 respones. It seem that url are set before run setUp().

Comment: You don't want to call `c.get('/group1/webindex/)` you want to call `c.get(url)` where `url = reverse('whaatever_app:group1')`.  Also I don't not think you are building your `url_patterns` correctly.  See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#example

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed, there is some bug in url_patterns. After modify the pattern and use the reverse function, everything work. Really appreciate.